# Dual space-dual norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Banach space $C^1([0,1])$ with the norm $||u||=|u(0)|+||u'||_{\infty}$.Characterize it's dual space in terms of other Banach spaces and find the dual norm. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: What can you say about the map 
\begin{align*}
  T \colon C^1[0,1] &\to \mathbb K \oplus_1 C^0[0,1]\\
     u &\mapsto \bigl(u(0), u'\bigr)
\end{align*}

Comment: I think OP needs more clarification

Comment: T is an isometric bijective operation, thus we can identify ($C^1$ with $K*C^0[0,1]$ and find out that it's dual space is $K*$(Radon measures) because the dual of K is K and the dual of $C^0$ are the Radon measures.

Comment: Exactly. And the dual of $T$ is an isometric isomorphism $T^* \colon \mathbb K \oplus_\infty M[0,1] \to C^1[0,1]^*$.